# Selenium nested selector does not work as expected

Tags: python, selenium, web, scrapy

I am writing a Scrapy spider crawling a list web page. The list item contains multiple attributes such as address and year. On the Scrapy official website there are instructions about nested selector:

```
>>> links = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "image")]')
>>> links.extract()
[u'<a href="image1.html">Name: My image 1 <br><img src="image1_thumb.jpg"></a>',
 u'<a href="image2.html">Name: My image 2 <br><img src="image2_thumb.jpg"></a>',
 u'<a href="image3.html">Name: My image 3 <br><img src="image3_thumb.jpg"></a>',
 u'<a href="image4.html">Name: My image 4 <br><img src="image4_thumb.jpg"></a>',
 u'<a href="image5.html">Name: My image 5 <br><img src="image5_thumb.jpg"></a>']

>>> for index, link in enumerate(links):
...     args = (index, link.xpath('@href').extract(), link.xpath('img/@src').extract())
...     print 'Link number %d points to url %s and image %s' % args

Link number 0 points to url [u'image1.html'] and image [u'image1_thumb.jpg']
Link number 1 points to url [u'image2.html'] and image [u'image2_thumb.jpg']
Link number 2 points to url [u'image3.html'] and image [u'image3_thumb.jpg']
Link number 3 points to url [u'image4.html'] and image [u'image4_thumb.jpg']
Link number 4 points to url [u'image5.html'] and image [u'image5_thumb.jpg']
```

But since I am crawling a dynamic website. So I was using the Selenium selector. I am trying to get the item list first:

```
item_selectors=self.selector.xpath("""//div[@class='info-column']""")
```

I print

```
item_selectors.extract()
```

It works perfect.

But when I try to get the address attributes from each item like this:

```
for item_selector in item_selectors:

    address_selector=item_selector.xpath("//span[contains(@ng-bind,'::card.buildingData.address')]/text()").extract()
```

in each iteration, I have the **address attribute list from the whole page**. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"//span[contains(@ng-bind,'::card.buildingData.address')]/text()"` is the reason you get attribute list from the whole page. The initial`//span` part tells the parser to look in the entire page, not in the `item_selector`.
The correct syntax for looking just within the `item_selector` would be just an additional leading `.`:

```
address_selector=item_selector.xpath(".//span[contains(@ng-bind,'::card.buildingData.address')]/text()").extract()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. any idea, where I can find a good xpath reference. I have searhed a lot but hardly found a "." instruction for this usage

Comment: @Jimmy Check out the [W3 Schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp).